# Change div content based on form field click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have text appear on the right side of the page as the user clicks on form fields. With each click on a different field, I am looking for the text to change in the same div with info about that field. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<html>
<head>  
<script>

$('#img1').click(function() {
  $('#aum').html('Text 1');
});

$('#img2').click(function() {
  $('#aum').html('Text 2');
});

$('#img3').click(function() {
  $('#aum').html('Text 3');
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="f1" name="f1"/>
<input type="text" id="f2" name="f2"/>
<input type="text" id="f3" name="f3"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div id="aum"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see no form :P Also, for it to work the way it is now, you should wrap your click handlers in the "document ready" event. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Not an accurate duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

## add click handlers onload

```
$( function(){
   // this is jQuery's shorthand for document.onload
});
```

## check your IDs

Your code references `$("#img1")` but no elements exist with that ID.

## Minmal Alterations Solution

https://jsfiddle.net/8h7fwjbc/

```
$(function(){  // document onready
    $('#f1').click(function() {
      updateAum('Text 1');
    });

    $('#f2').click(function() {
      updateAum('Text 2');
    });

    $('#f3').click(function() {
      updateAum('Text 3');
    });
});

function updateAum(content) {
    $('#aum').html(content);
}
```

## Better Solution, use data-tags

https://jsfiddle.net/8h7fwjbc/1/

#### HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="f1" name="f1" data-aum="Text 1"/>
<input type="text" id="f2" name="f2" data-aum="Text 2"/>
<input type="text" id="f3" name="f3" data-aum="Text 3"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div id="aum"></div>
```

#### JS

```
$(function(){  // document onready
    $('[data-aum]').click(function() {
      updateAum( $(this).attr('data-aum') );
    });
});

function updateAum(content) {
    $('#aum').html(content);
}
```

Comment: Would check your solution but my rep score is too low. The only trick is to make sure the script appears below the form. thanks.

Comment: Since you wrote the question, you should be able to accept the answer. From the stackoverflow intro, "The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"."

Comment: If you can, keep the js in a separate file, and include it in the head tags.